# Convert an int to a percent or decimal

Tags: java, integer

I'm reading some input as integers. First input is a population of cats and dogs, second input is an integer that represents a percentage of dogs that population. I'm trying to calculate how many dogs and cats we have with these two integers.

```
dogs = population * percentage
cats = population - dogs
```

The math is easy, what I'm having some trouble with is using integers to get these values.

The inputs have to be read in as integers.

Comment: What trouble do you have? Where is your code, what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: @Talen Use a int for decimal less numbers, use a double (or float) for numbers with a decimal, you can de `double num = scanner.nextInt()`

Comment: @RealSkeptic Good idea. The integer is read in as 40, and I'll need to divide by 100. Suggest this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: You'd better divide it by 100.0, or you'll get 0 as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the percentage is a number like 0.4, you can't read it as an integer. If it is 40, then you can read it - but then you can't just multiply the population by it - you need to divide by 100.

Remember to divide after you have multiplied, otherwise you might end up with a zero because of integer division. `percentage / 100` will give you zero. But `population * percentage / 100` is going to give you a reasonable number, provided the population is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can't have a half-dog or half-cat. so basically you can just do it like this:

```
dogs = (population * percentage)/100;
cats = (population - dogs);
```

as `dogs` and `population` must to be Integers.

you can also check that this is really what happens by:

```
if((dogs+cats)!=population) System.out.println(**error message about wrong input**);
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you share what code you're using for input?  When I ask a user for input, I usually have to use a ParseInt function to convert their string input into a number.  For example:

```
String Dogs = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter number of dogs");
Integer.parseInt(Dogs);
System.out.println(Dogs);
```

That last line is to print out our input that's been converted from a string to an integer, just to check that it works.
I hope this helped!

Answer (score -3):

Use a scanner or buffered reader to read in the data and put it into an int variable.